# Splitting string into strings using strtok() not working

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I have a problem with regards to separating the contents of a string passed to a function. The function is called with a string like this:

```
ADD:Nathaniel:50
```

Where ADD will be the protocol name, Nathaniel will be the key, and 50 will be the value, all separated with a `:`.

My code looks like this:

```
bool add_to_list(char* buffer){

  char key[40];
  char value[40];
  int* token;

  char buffer_copy[1024];
  const char delim[2] = ":";

  strcpy(buffer_copy, buffer);

  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  //strcpy(key, token);

  printf("%d",token);
  printf("%p",token);

  while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok (NULL, delim);
  }
  //strcpy(value, token);

  printf("%s", key);
  printf("%s", value);
  push(key, value);

  return true;
}
```

What I am trying to do is store each key and value in a separate variable, using `strtok()`. Note that I am trying to store the second and third values (`Nathaniel` and `50`) not the first bit (`ADD`).

When I run the code, it gives me a segmentation fault, so I am guessing that I am trying to access an invalid memory address rather than a value. I just need to store the second and third bit of the string. Can anyone help please?

EDIT: 
I have changed the code to look like this:

```
bool add_to_list(char* buffer){

char *key, *value, *token;

const char *delim = ":";

token = strtok(buffer, delim);

//printf("%d",token);
printf("%s",token);

key = strtok(NULL, delim);
value = strtok(NULL, delim);

printf("%s", key);
printf("%s", value);
//push(key, value);

return true;
}
```

But I am still getting the same segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Comment: You never store anything in `key` or `value`.

Comment: `int* token;` --> `char *token;`

Comment: `const char[2] delim` -> `const char* delim`

Comment: And for g-d sake, use `strsep` instead of awful `strtok`.

Answer (score 4):

The first call to `strtok()` needs to provide the string to scan. You only use `NULL` on the repeated calls, so it will keep processing the rest of the string. SO the first call should be:

```
token = strtok(buffer_copy, delim);
```

Then when you want to get the key and value, you need to copy them to the arrays:

```
token = strtok(NULL, delim);
key = strcpy(token);
token = strtok(NULL, delim);
value = strcpy(token);
```

You don't need a loop, since you just want to extract these two values.

Actually, you don't need to declare `key` and `value` as arrays, you could use pointers:

```
char *key, *value;
```

Then you can do:

```
token = strtok(buffer_copy, delim);
key = strtok(NULL, delim);
value = strtok(NULL, delim);
```

Comment: I am getting some warnings with regards to: 

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     token = strtok(buffer_copy, delim);

What is happening here and is there a way i can remove the error?

Comment: `token` should be `char*`, not `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that when you first call `strtok`, the first parameter should be the string you want to parse, so not:

```
strcpy(buffer_copy, buffer);
token = strtok(NULL, delim);
```

but

```
strcpy(buffer_copy, buffer);
token = strtok(buffer_copy, delim);
```

Additionally when you detect the tokens in your `while` loop, you are throwing them away. You want to do something at that point (or simply unroll the loop and call `strtok` three times).

Also:

```
const char* delim = ":";
```

would be a more conventional way of ensuring a `NUL` terminated string than:

```
const char delim[2] = ":";
```

Also consider using `strtok_r` not `strtok` as `strtok` is not thread-safe and horrible. Whilst you are not using threads here (it seems), you might as well get into good practice.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the strtok_r function? I am trying to find information about it but i am finding it difficult to understand. 

Also, my system will be like a small server so i will have multiple threads, hence why i am intrigued about using the safe version, plus its good ethics

Comment: Re `strtok_r`, the manual page is a useful resource, but here's what you should do. For each string tokenization you want to do (i.e. once in the example here), add `char *save=NULL;` before the first use (technically the initialisation is optional), then add `&save` as an additional parameter to each use of `strtok` in that tokenization, and change `strtok` to `strtok_r`. This means `strtok_r` will store its state between calls in `save` and not in an internal static buffer, so you have thread safety.